Irregularities with flag responses
I'm having trouble understanding why the response to my flag on this answer was :
Text accompanying the flag:
It's telling the op to physically assault someone, I have had accounts banned for way less. "Personally, I would just kick them in the shin with each comment (hard enough to leave a week-long bruise), but you wanted to avoid confrontation, and that's what HR is for."
Response:
Declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention
Clearly, this answer is inciting violence and physically assaulting someone.
There are other flags in similar situations (I think an answer is not fit for the website. I think a question isn't fit for the website and since I can't VTC, I flag it etc.) that are getting the same answer. Should I not flag for these reasons ? I'm only opening this question because I feel like if I keep flagging and getting these responses, maybe I'm misinterpreting what they are supposed to be used for.
More examples:
Link
This answer is not taking into account what the asker said, the colleague never insulted anyone, and talking to the manager would be no good. – Or4ng3h4t Nov 2, 2023 at 15:01   Declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer
Link
I think this should be on law, since it's not a problem specifically about the workplace, but about whether he can be fired for selling the swag. Since I can't VTC I'm flagging it – Or4ng3h4t Jan 12 at 10:36   Declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention
I'm not contesting the ruling of the moderators, simply asking for clarification on what I should do in case I encounter the same problem in the future.

I think I handled the shin kicker a couple of times. I didn't see them telling the OP to assault anyone. The wording specifically said that's not an option in this case. It's generally best not to get excited over a couple of words without taking the context into account.

@Kilisi I agree, but I have been timed out and got my access restricted for a full month over way less than giving my opinion. I have been penalized for making fun of an acronym, imagine what would have happened to my account if I had given my opinion.

You've never been timed out by me. I've also been suspended over ridiculous trifles, even just cultural misunderstandings by people who assume their culture applies everywhere or is somehow superior, but now I'm a mod I'm not going to do it to others.

@Kilisi Oh sorry I didn't mean it was by you, I was just trying to explain the petty reason why I flag things like that.

First up, the answer on the "criticising habits question: I'm not the mod that handled that flag, and I'm not sure why the mod who did declined it. I've deleted the answer, the suggestion may or may not have been flippant but posts suggesting violence aren't acceptable.
Next the "eliminate demoralization" question: Again I'm not the mod who handled your flags on that answer but I would have done the same. Neither "custom" nor "Not An Answer" flags are appropriate for "I don't like/agree with this answer" or even "I don't think this is a complete answer", if both cases a comment suggesting improvement and/or a downvote is more appropriate.
Lastly the "swag" question: Didn't handle this flag either but I'd agree with it. You can flag questions as "not suitable for this site" (as opposed to a custom flag as you raised here) as someone without VTC privileges which should punt the question into the review queues for users with those privileges to then vote on.

Okey, thank you for the clarification, ill stop using custom flags and use more the ones that already exist.
